# psql: could not connect to server: No route to host

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, psql

Currently I can't connect to PostgreSQL from client. The client IP is "10.0.0.121" and my server IP is "10.0.0.104".

When I attempt to connect with `psql -U postgres -h 10.0.0.121` I get the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No route to host
Is the server running on host "10.0.0.104" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've configured my server:

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             10.0.0.121/32           md5
```

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432
```

Do I need to configured anything else?

Comment: Also make sure you reloaded the pg_hba: `select pg_reload_conf();`

Comment: "No route to host" means that psql can't even locate the server. It's probably a network issue, not a Postgres configuration issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the file **pg_hba.conf** because you are using the mask of 32 bits which would give access to the specified ip   `10.0.0.120` only, if you want to take a segment try to use a mask less than 32 bits (Ex. `10.0.0.120/24`), if you want to try the package `nmap` to list the ports exposed by the ip `10.0.0.121` in question